# Should a comma ALWAYS come before any type of quote?

Tags: punctuation, quotations

I am finishing up an essay, and my teacher has marked on my essay that there should be a comma before every set of quotation marks.

I had commas where I deemed suitable, but in some instances I find that the use of a comma would make the sentence sound really weird.

For example, sentences in the form of

> All morning, Adam "avoided saying anything to Bob that required a form of address", referring to him only as "him", or "the kid".

To me, it sounds weird to have it become

> All morning, Adam, "avoided saying anything to Bob that required a form of address", referring to him only as, "him", or, "the kid".

Can someone please explain to me whether I should use commas in places demonstrated above, and the general rule for this?

Thanks!

Edit: I specifically am looking for the answer of whether there should be commas before quotes that are *integrated* into the sentence, where the quote directly flows from the introductory text.

Comment: We have questions about comma usage about once a day. The answer is that they are mostly stylistic, or up to the author or publisher. Your teacher may insist that his/her preference is right. That doesn't make it so. I wouldn't use them before every quotation. You could check other style guides.

Comment: I'm not sure whether wars have ever been fought over this point, but definitely a few street rumbles.  (But in your example the added quote seems weird.)

Comment: This question is different from the possible duplicate found by @Laurel.  That one was about quotes that come after "saying" or "said."

Comment: @aparente001 There's really two questions here: (1) the general rule (2) in a list. I voted for (1)'s dupe, but I also found a dupe for (2) [here](: english.stackexchange.com/a/114403/191178), which I edited into the comment. My hope is that OP will find all the answers they asked for between the two.

Comment: The Oxford Manual of Style is with your teacher in this matter. One problem with your example sentence is that it is hard to know who is being quoted in the first set of quotation marks. They appear to be redundant. Maybe this is what you should discuss with your teacher.

Comment: @Laurel - Ah, yes, I see it.  The second link seems somewhat more helpful.  Still, I think a clear Q and A on this would be worthwhile.   (I'm surprised there isn't a better matching duplicate!)  However, I think it would be reasonable to ask the OP to show s/he's tried to find the answer.

Comment: @Mick I am quoting a phrase from the novel that I'm writing this analytical essay on.

Answer (score -1):

To make your teacher happy, you could do the following to introduce your quote from the text you are analyzing:

> All morning, "[Adam] avoided saying anything to Bob that required a form of address," referring to him only as "him," or "the kid."